# Angular Parent and Child Modules Chunk sizes issue

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have application structure like this:

```
1. app
   1. Shared Module
   2. Modules
      1. ExternalSourceModule
         Child Modules
            1. SourceModule
            2. EntityModule
         ExternalSourceSharedModule
```

1. `ExternalSourceSharedModule` imports `SharedModule` because shared module has application level dependencies
2. `ExternalSourceModule` and it child modules imports `ExternalSourceSharedModule` because `ExternalSourceSharedModule` has some dependencies which `ExternalSourceModule` and it's `Child Modules Needs`

Code of `ExternalSourceSharedModule`:

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [
     ShareModule,
   ]
   ...
});
```

Code of `ExternalSourceModule` which imports `ExternalSourceSharedModule`

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [
    ExternalSourceSharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(externalSourceRoutes)
  ],
   ...
});
```

Now `ExternalSourceModule` Lazy Loads it's child Module:

```
export const externalSourceRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: 'source', loadChildren: './modules/source/source.module#SourceModule' },
   { path: 'entity', loadChildren: './modules/entity/entity.module#EntityModule' }
]
```

`ExternalSourceSharedModule` has dependencies for `ExternalSourceModule` as well as `SourceModule` and `EntityModule` So i've to import that `ExternalSourceSharedModule` in `SourceModule` and `EntityModule` as well code:

`EntityModule:`

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ExternalSourceSharedModule
    RouterModule.forChild(entityRoutes)
  ],
  ...
});

export class EntityModule {}
```

`SourceModule:`

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ExternalSourceSharedModule
    RouterModule.forChild(entityRoutes)
  ],
  ...
});

export class SourceModule {}
```

I'm using `@angular/cli` for my project, Doing `ng build` returns this:

```
Time: 9020ms
chunk    {0} 0.chunk.js, 0.chunk.js.map 1.17 MB {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {9} [rendered]
chunk    {1} 1.chunk.js, 1.chunk.js.map 1.19 MB {0} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {9} [rendered]
chunk    {2} 2.chunk.js, 2.chunk.js.map 394 kB {0} {1} {3} {4} {5} {6} {9} [rendered]
chunk    {3} 3.chunk.js, 3.chunk.js.map 1.44 MB {0} {1} {2} {4} {5} {6} {9} [rendered]
chunk    {4} 4.chunk.js, 4.chunk.js.map 1.18 MB {0} {1} {2} {3} {5} {6} {9} [rendered]
chunk    {5} 5.chunk.js, 5.chunk.js.map 5.29 kB {0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {6} {9}
chunk    {6} 6.chunk.js, 6.chunk.js.map 11.8 kB {0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {9}
chunk    {7} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 158 kB {11} [initial]
chunk    {8} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 256 kB {11} [initial]
chunk    {9} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 122 kB {10} [initial] [rendered]
chunk   {10} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 4.58 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk   {11} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry]
```

Let assume:

- 1.chunk.js is `ExternalSourceModule`
- 0.chunk.js is `EntityModule` which is a child of `ExternalSourceModule`
- 3.chunk.js is `SourceModule` which is a child of `ExternalSourceModule`

You can see the size of these chunks which has > 1 MB now when i remove `ExternalSourceSharedModule` from `EntityModule` and `SourceModule` then doing `ng build` returns:

```
Time: 8779ms
chunk    {0} 0.chunk.js, 0.chunk.js.map 84.3 kB {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {9} [rendered]
chunk    {1} 1.chunk.js, 1.chunk.js.map 1.19 MB {0} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {9} [rendered]
chunk    {2} 2.chunk.js, 2.chunk.js.map 394 kB {0} {1} {3} {4} {5} {6} {9} [rendered]
chunk    {3} 3.chunk.js, 3.chunk.js.map 355 kB {0} {1} {2} {4} {5} {6} {9} [rendered]
chunk    {4} 4.chunk.js, 4.chunk.js.map 89.3 kB {0} {1} {2} {3} {5} {6} {9} [rendered]
chunk    {5} 5.chunk.js, 5.chunk.js.map 5.29 kB {0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {6} {9}
chunk    {6} 6.chunk.js, 6.chunk.js.map 11.8 kB {0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {9}
chunk    {7} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 158 kB {11} [initial]
chunk    {8} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 256 kB {11} [initial]
chunk    {9} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 122 kB {10} [initial] [rendered]
chunk   {10} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 4.58 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk   {11} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry]
```

Now if you see the sizes of chunks reduces to below < 1 MB so the questions becomes is there is any technique where i can tell to `ExternalSourceModule` that use `ExternalSourceSharedModule` for it's child modules as well, so that i don't need to import `ExternalSourceSharedModule` in child modules.

Currently removing `ExternalSourceSharedModule` from child modules breaks my application.

`webpack-bundle-analyzer` Screenshot:
https://box.everhelper.me/attachment/1011387/e86e6209-48b7-464d-912d-a5daa4f4cca4/227833-DmqHiBXBvJD2Puep/screen.png

Environment: 
@angular: 4
@angular/cli: 1.0

Hope i have cleared my question.

Comment: are you just  using `ng build` or `ng build --prod` ?

Comment: i'm doing just `ng build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @brijmcq is missing something.

@touqeer-shafi, you should turn on `aot` option with angular-cli. As from my project, I have similar structure too, and I don't have that problem.

run a command like this:

```
ng build -prod --aot
```

and see the build stats.

> `ng build`, `ng build -prod` and `ng build -prod --aot` produce different output bundles structure.

You can also use [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/th0r/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to analyze which modules are bundled into which chunks. If you still have problem with the suggested command, please paste the screenshot in webpack-bundle-analyzer's report of each bundle. Then we could get more information for further help.

Update 1:

**What I talk is based on @angular/cli@1.2.0 for now.** Otherwise, we may not reach to the shore.

Comment: `ng build --prod --aot` also produces the same results.

Comment: can you run webpack-bundler-analyzer and capture a screenshot?

Comment: and it's `-prod`, not `--prod` with the latest angular-cli.

Comment: `ng build -prod --aot` also produces the same results, as far as `webpack-bundler-analyzer` i will share the results with you once i've implement it on my machine.

Comment: here is the `webpack-bundler-analyzer`: https://box.everhelper.me/attachment/1011387/e86e6209-48b7-464d-912d-a5daa4f4cca4/227833-DmqHiBXBvJD2Puep/screen.png

Comment: By default, doing `ng build --prod` is aot enabled

Comment: It's weird that most of your chunks have `lodash-es` and `mobx` bundled, I guess you may misuse some module imports? And, You should try @angular/cli@1.2.0

Comment: @e-cloud after updating to `@angular/cli@1.2.x` issue is now fixed, doing `ng build -prod --aot` reduces the sizes of the chunk. thank you for you help, thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are lazy loading your modules ( Source and Entity modules ) you need to import `ExternalSourceSharedModule` to each of the modules. Taken from the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq)

> What if I import the same module twice?
>
> That's not a problem. When three modules all import Module 'A',
>   Angular evaluates Module 'A' once, the first time it encounters it,
>   and doesn't do so again.

To make your build smaller, try to do a production build ( if you are using the latest angular-cli, using just --prod is AOT enabled.

```
ng build --prod
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: doing `ng build --prod` produces chunks > 1 MB, only `vendor` chunk reduces the size.