# Angular 4 with Angular Material: change the number of imported module doesn't change the size of the build

Tags: angular, angular-material2

i'm a newbie on Angular, i have write my first app and i have noticed that a blank app, builded with:

```
ng build --prod
```

is 270 KB (of javascripts), with Material Design is 960 KB (of javascripts).

The strange fact is: if i comment some material module (see material-components.module.ts) the size doesn't change (always 960 kb).

The "compiler" seem always include all material modules.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import 'hammerjs';
import { MaterialComponentsModule } from './material-components.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MaterialComponentsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

material-components.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {
  //MdAutocompleteModule, 
  MdButtonModule, 
  MdCardModule, 
  //MdCheckboxModule, 
  //MdDatepickerModule, 
  //MdDialogModule,
  //MdGridListModule, 
  //MdIconModule, 
  //MdInputModule, 
  //MdListModule,
  //MdMenuModule, 
  //MdNativeDateModule, 
  //MdProgressBarModule, 
  //MdProgressSpinnerModule, 
  //MdSelectModule,
  //MdSidenavModule,
  //MdSliderModule,
  //MdSlideToggleModule, 
  //MdSnackBarModule, 
  //MdTabsModule, 
  //MdToolbarModule, 
  //MdTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    //MdAutocompleteModule, 
    MdButtonModule, 
    MdCardModule, 
    //MdCheckboxModule, 
    //MdDatepickerModule, 
    //MdDialogModule,
    //MdGridListModule, 
    //MdIconModule, 
    //MdInputModule, 
    //MdListModule,
    //MdMenuModule, 
    //MdNativeDateModule, 
    //MdProgressBarModule, 
    //MdProgressSpinnerModule, 
    //MdSelectModule,
    //MdSidenavModule,
    //MdSliderModule,
    //MdSlideToggleModule, 
    //MdSnackBarModule, 
    //MdTabsModule, 
    //MdToolbarModule, 
    //MdTooltipModule 
  ]
})
export class MaterialComponentsModule { }
```

Comment: If I'm not saying dumb things, importing only allows you to use the Typescript definitions. What is used in the project is actually the JS, that is compiled. And since you have angular material as a dependency, it will build the whole library.

Comment: @trichetriche actually tree shaking should eliminate the unused code

Comment: @PierreDuc wath i do for enable tree shaking?

Comment: @PierreDuc I see, but tree shaking should occur at build, right ? This means that OP, you would have to build you application twice with `ng build`, and compare the size at this time

Comment: @trichetriche tree shaking will be enabled using `--prod`, so yes, I have no idea why his final build size is not smaller. And no, twice `ng build` will not make a difference

Comment: It is because when you import something from `@angular/material`, it exports the whole bundle. There was an issue for it but apparently they didn't do anything. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3258

Comment: @PierreDuc I meant build it twice to compare the sizes, one with all the imports and one with only a bunch of them, sorry I've not expressed myself correctly !

Comment: @trichetriche but that's exactly what he did ;) `ng build --prod`

Comment: Yes I agree, but to compare 2 builds, you need to build your project twice ! This is why I said to build it twice, just so he can compare the size of both builds

Comment: i'm also have some kind of question `ng build` does not reduce size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972548/angular-parent-and-child-modules